# Call Socket IO instance from a component or API route on NextJS

Tags: reactjs, sockets, socket.io, next.js

I'm trying to call to my socket server instance from an API Route endpoint for to send a broadcast to all the Socket IO clients when I save a new record in the database.

Socket IO is running properly in my NextJS server.

I've created a custom ./server/index.ts for to run the NextJS server and Socket.io server sharing the same port.

The clients connect successfully to Socket IO server. But now I would like that when from the browser call to an API route like this /api/save I can use my Socket IO server instance for to emit a broadcast.

But I don't know how to get an instance of Socket IO server from other files in the project.

Thank you.

./server/index.ts

```js
import "reflect-metadata";
import { createServer } from 'http'
import { parse } from 'url'
import next from 'next'
import socketIo from "socket.io";

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT || '3000', 10);
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {

    const http = createServer((req, res) => {
        const parsedUrl = parse(req.url!, true);
        const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;

        if (pathname === '/a') {
            app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
        } else if (pathname === '/b') {
            app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
        } else {
            handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
        }
    }).listen(port);

    const ioServer = socketIo(http);
    ioServer.on("connection", function (socket) {
        console.log('An user has connected!');
        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            console.log('An user has disconnected');
        });
    });

    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
    console.log(
        `> Server listening at http://localhost:${port} as ${
            dev ? 'development' : process.env.NODE_ENV
        }`
    );


});
```

Comment: How did you fix this error bud?

Comment: I have the same issue do you mind checking this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77330485/how-to-access-socket-io-io-instance-from-different-api-route-in-next-js

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to export the instance just create a function to perform the task in socket file and export the function and use it wherever you want.

Comment: Hi Santgurial, for to implement your solution I find the same issue. How to call to Socket IO instance from another file of the project. FYI I've attached my ./server/index.ts file where I create the Socket IO instance. Thank you.

Comment: You should create the socket server on a different file and not on the server index file then in that file initiate a server instance and create all functions you need that uses that instance then you will export those functions and use them in other files. See this to learn exporting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export