# How to access socket.io io instance from different api route in Next JS

Tags: next.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io in NextJS. So the io instance is created on one API route. It has to be this way since you need the socket nstance inside the response parameter of the API request. Here is an the socket.ts file where the io instance is defined.

**socket.ts (pages/api/socket.ts)**

```
import {
  ClientToServerEvents,
  NextApiResponseWithSocket,
  ServerToClientEvents,
} from "@/types/socket-types";
import type { NextApiRequest } from "next";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

export const handler = async (
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponseWithSocket
) => {
  if (!res.socket.server.io) {
    console.log("First use, starting socket.io");

    const io = new Server<ClientToServerEvents, ServerToClientEvents>(
      res.socket.server,
      { path: "/api/socket", addTrailingSlash: false }
    );

    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      socket.on("helloFromClient", (msg) => {
        console.log(`${msg}`);
        socket.emit("helloFromServer", `Hey ${socket.id}!`);
      });

    });

    res.socket.server.io = io;
  } else {
    console.log("socket.io already running");
  }
  res.end();
};

export default handler;
```

Now i have another API route. This route is NOT called from the frontend. It is a callback that i use to receive notifications from a 3rd party payments provider. So in that route when a client pays for something i want to send a socket message to that client.

**stk-push-callback.ts (pages/api/stk-push-callback.ts)**

```
import {
  STKPushErrorCallbackBody,
  STKPushSuccessfulCallbackBody,
} from "@/types/globals";
import {
  ClientToServerEvents,
  NextApiResponseWithSocket,
  ServerToClientEvents,
} from "@/types/socket-types";
import { NextApiRequest } from "next";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const POST = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponseWithSocket) => {
  const text: STKPushSuccessfulCallbackBody | STKPushErrorCallbackBody =
    req.body;

  const io = new Server<ClientToServerEvents, ServerToClientEvents>(
    res.socket.server,
    { path: "/api/socket", addTrailingSlash: false }
  );

  if (text.Body.stkCallback.ResultCode === 0) {
    console.log("success", JSON.stringify(text));

    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      socket.on("awaitingPayment", (clientId) => {
        io.to(clientId).emit("paymentSuccess", {
          socketId: socket.id,
        });
      });
    });
  } else {
    console.log("error", JSON.stringify(text));
    io.on("awaiting-payment", (socket) => {
      socket.emit("paymentError", { message: "payment error" });
    });
  }
};

export default POST;
```

Well in my current implementation i make a new io instance. That does not work as i need. This is because i need the io instance on which the client is connected to make the messaging work. **How can i reuse the IO instance in my `socket.ts` file in my `stk-push-callback.ts` file? Please Help.**